# Adding border-radius to TinyMCE textarea

Tags: iframe, tinymce, css

Is it possible to add a border-radius to TinyMCE'd textareas? It's kinda killing me that I have rounded corners on my input fields etc, but I can't get it working on my textarea.. Probably because TinyMCE is turning it into an IFRAME? Is there any way around this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: please give some code to understand better

Comment: what he wants is perfectly clear. he would like to have a border around the iframe that tinymce creates, good question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the [editor_css setting](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_css).
This css gets applied after the default tinymce css is loaded thus overwrite the default one.

I created a file called editor.css containing the following

```
.defaultSkin table.mceLayout {border:1px solid black}
```

and set the tinymce parameter using editor_css

```
editor_css : 'path_to_css'.'/editor.css',
```

This creates a nice thin black line around the editor.

Comment: This seems to work for a 1px solid black border, but it doesn't do anything when I add border-radius. More importantly though, it messes up my TinyMCE buttons :( Thanks though!

Comment: can you explain, what exactly gets messed up? i am sure that only the css in the editor.css needs to be set correctly

Comment: what browser do you use? IE is capable of handling border-radius till version 9

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a border radius to a tinyMCE text area you will have to add the following css rules at the bottom of to the file: /themes/advanced/skins/default/ui.css. 
Note: If your are using a custom skin you will have to add these rules inside the css file you created for that skin.

```
#article_tbl, #article_ifr{
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */    
}

$article_tbl{
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

#article_ifr{
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;    
}

#article_tbl{
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */    
}

.mceToolbar{         
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.defaultSkin table.mceLayout tr.mceLast td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to programmatically add classes to TinyMCE container on init:

```
textarea.tinymce({
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function() {
            editor.getContainer().className += ' with-border';
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.with-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See [Integration and Setup](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) | TinyMCE documentation

> The `setup` option allows you to specify an event that will be executed before the TinyMCE editor instance is rendered.

Comment: It works, just needed to force the style `border: 1px solid black !important`